# rails 4 unpermitted params nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, nested-forms

I know there are alot of these kinds of posts on SO, and I think Ive read and tried each of them, all without success.

I have Post and Image models that I need to work together with a many to one relationship.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  mount_uploader :file, images_uploader
end
```

Here is the post_parms declaration in my posts controller, which includes all of the fields in my image model migration.

```
private
 def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, image_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :file])
end
```

and here is my post creation form where, I hope to allow multiple image asset creation with each post.

```
<%= form_for @post, html: {class: "pure-form pure-form-stacked"} do |post| %>

<%= post.fields_for :image, :html => { :multipart => true } do |image| %>
    <%= image.label :file, "Upload Image:" %>
    <%= image.file_field :file, multiple: true %>   
<% end %>

<fieldset class="post-form">
    <%= post.label :title %>
    <%= post.text_field :title %>

    <%= post.label :content %>
    <%= post.text_area :content, :class => "redactor", :rows => 40, :cols => 120 %>
</fieldset>

<div class = "button-box">
    <%= post.submit class: "pure-button pure-button-primary" %>
    <%= link_to "Cancel", posts_path, :class => "pure-button" %>
</div>
```

Despite repeated effort and reading every post I can find on this topic, I'm still getting:

```
Unpermitted parameters: image
```

The trouble here is that this error provides no clue where to start looking for the problem.  Since Im not really sure where to look next I thought I would post it here looking for more professional opinions.

Comment: Is this issue resolved? If not, Can u share the content of PostController?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the `Post` model as below:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :images
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :images ## Add this
end
```

This way upon form submission you would receive the image attributes in key `images_attributes` and not `image` which you are currently receiving which is causing the warning as `Unpermitted parameters: image`

As you have `1-M relationship` between `Post` and `Image`

You need to update `post_params` as below:

```
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, images_attributes: [:id, :post_id, :file])
end
```

Use `images_attributes` (**Notice plural images**) and NOT `image_attributes`  (**Notice singular image**)

And change `fields_for` in your view as

```
<%= post.fields_for :images, :html => { :multipart => true } do |image| %>
```

Use `images` (**Notice plural**) and NOT `image`  (**Notice singular**)

**UPDATE**

To resolve `uninitialized constant Post::Image` error

Update `Image` model as below:

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  ## Updated mount_uploader
  mount_uploader :file, ImagesUploader, :mount_on => :file
end
```

Also, suggested to remove `multiple: :true` from

```
<%= ff.file_field :file, multiple: true %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Kirti, after fixing all of these errors, I am now getting "uninitialized constant Post::Image" when I try to load my form, interestingly when I change the "post.fields_for :images" back to the plural ":image" there are no errors.  Im not really sure where Im going wrong.